# Serenity BDD with JBehave loading duplicate requirements

Tags: java, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I am trying to run a set of JBehave user stories with Serenity. While generating the 
Serenity test report with the Serenity-Maven Plugin, I discovered that the HTML reports, and the corresponding console output loads the same JBehave story twice.

Is there any way to prevent the story from loading twice in the requirements?

For reference, a snippet of the console output is provided, with certain sensitive details redacted:

```
[INFO] LOADED REQUIREMENTS:
REQUIREMENTS:
    - story : Failure {id: src/test/resources/stories/Failure.story, displayName: 'Failure', path: Failure.story, parent: 'null'}
    - story : Failure {id: /Users/<REDACTED>/Repo/src/test/resources/stories/Failure.story, displayName: 'Failure', path: Failure.story, parent: 'null'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by upgrading the Serenity Maven Plugin from:

> 2.0.89

to:

> 2.1.8

Comment: Hello, could you put what versions in your dependencies are you working with? I will appreciate if you put the detail of your pom.xml.

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi, i am using the following versions for Serenity dependencies: Serenity-Core: 2.0.90, Serenity-JUnit: 2.0.90, Serenity-JBehave: 1.46